# Different cloud init command based on AMI

Tags: terraform, cloud-init, terraform-template-file

I have a question about terraform and cloud init. I wonder if anyone could help here...
Suppose I have an AWS instance that I provision like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  ami                  = "xxxxxxx"
  instance_type        = "t2.nano"
...
  user_data = data.template_cloudinit_config.init.rendered
```

The cloud init configuration is loaded from a file. Here is a sample:

```
#cloud-config
#

bootcmd: 
  - [echo, "Ubuntu"]
  - [echo, "RedHat"]
  - [echo, "AmazonLinux"]
```

What I would like to do is to run the first echo when I choose an AMI that is Ubuntu, the second one when it's red hat, and the last one when it's amazon linux. Is it possible to do this with cloud config? I see there is a Scripts Vendor(1) in the documentation. But I'm not sure if we could use that feature from a template file loaded from disk. Any idea?
Of course I could easily create three different files and load them separately based on a variable. I only wonder if there is a nicer solution.

(1) https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#scripts-vendor

Comment: I'm not too familiar with cloudinit but instead of the echo statement can you run this? cat /etc/os-release <-- That should display the OS on all those platforms along with some other info.

Comment: Hi Paulg, I could do that yes. But, I was more willing to try to create one cloud init file and depending on the platform, some commands would be executed and some not. My example was only to make it easy to understand. Thank you for the reply anyway :)